# Capturing cellular network packets on iOS?

Tags: ios, 3g, 4g

I found an article that discuss capturing network packets traveling over Wifi on iOS: http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/?p=519

**How can I achieve the same thing for cellular (i.e. 3G, 4G) network packets?** I'm trying to figure out what network protocol Skype used to implement live chat on iOS in light of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936819/apple-policy-for-http-live-streaming-apps) restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a great answer to your question, but you could try:

1. Use Skype to call a Mac or PC and watch the connection from the other side using a packet sniffer
2. Get an AT&T 3G Microcell and put a packet sniffer on its Ethernet connection
3. Jailbreak the device and put a packet sniffer on it

I don't think any of those solutions are going to work well if Skype uses secure connections. #1 won't see the setup conversation with Skype's server either. #3 seems like your best bet if you have a spare device.

Comment: I have access to a jail-broken device. How can I sniff outgoing cellular packets in such a case?

Comment: I have never done it, but a Google search brings up http://code.google.com/p/pirni-derv/ and http://www.ijailbreak.com/applications/learn-how-to-sniff-wireless-passwords-with-pirni/ . Could work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a jailbrocken device device to run capture on it. You can sniff traffic via your mac device.
This is what you want I believe. Starting from iOS5 Apple added support for RVI interface. So if you're running an OSX device, you can connect your iOS to OSX with a VRI network and enjoy the world of 3G/2G.

What regards to Skype:
Skype uses it's protocol for chat, though packets are transmitted in TCP. Capturing these packets what give as much info as you can suppose to.
Audio is sent in UDP packets while on a call(just have a test yesterday).
Hope this will help.

Comment: I wonder what this answer is not the accepted. I just used RVI as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECIOSPACKETTRACING and here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices/ and it works great. You can even capture data from Cellular Data network :)